# Windows forms: asynchronous web service ("web reference") IOCP in a single "console thread"

Tags: c#

I have a windows forms application, which might also be run without GUI (and GUI message pump). If so, it calls a web service/web reference object's async method, waits for the metod to complete, and finishes execution.

Now, as far as I understand web service IOCP, it completes async HTTP requests in the very thread that called async method. What I don't understand, is why it can do it while the thread is waiting on a wait handle object.

```
static class Program {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static int Main(string[] args) {

        if (args.Length == 0) {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
            return 0;
        } else {
            AutoResetEvent waitEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            WebServiceWrapper w = new WebServiceWrapper();
            w.Finished += delegate(object o, EventArgs e) {
                waitEvent.Set();
            }
            w.Start(); 
            waitEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

WebServiceWrapper.Start() method internally calls an async method of a web-reference-type object (autogenerated by Visual Studio after I added the web reference). On the completion of async call, WebServiceWrapper.Finished event is called. But this happens when the thread to complete the call is already waiting.

So, my first thought was, the program should hang - but it works like a charm. Could someone please explain to me, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, as far as I understand web service IOCP, it completes async HTTP requests in the very thread that called async method. What I don't understand, is why it can do it while the thread is waiting on a wait handle object.

Yes this is not possible and it doesn't work that way. A busy thread cannot be hijacked. All code a thread ever runs is chosen by it itself.

When an IO completes the following sequence of evens unfolds:

1. The hardware notifies the kernel or device driver of completion
2. The IRP is completed
3. Completion is delivered to the calling Win32 app (which is the CLR)
4. The CLR calls the registered callback delegate for this IO

I'm a little vague on the details because a lot of this is implementation details and can vary with the concrete situation.

The IO completion work is executed on the thread-pool. You don't have any guarantees about the concrete thread executing it.

`async/await` is another layer on top of this. Depending on the registered `SynchronizationContext` your code might resume on another thread because the awaiter marshals the call across. For example in a WinForms environment it eventually results in a call to `Control.Invoke` or similar.

In your `else` branch no sync context is set, so all completion work happens on the thread-pool.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I got confused by how it works within WinForms. After reading your reply, I added some code to print the ManagedThreadId to consone, before and inside my "Finished event": the threads are different.